# .NET Core 2.1 using React template - Unexpected token < json at position 0 while using "fetch()"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to setup a basic CRUD application using .NET Core 2.1 with the React template. I have a SQL Server DB with 2 tables : `tblEmployee`, `tblCities`.

I've created my models using `Scaffold-DbContext` successfully. And I added my connection string to `appsettings.json`.

In my Models folder, I added a `DataAccessLayer.cs` (class) with some functions to access my context.

Example :

```cs
private readonly CoreReactAppContext db = new CoreReactAppContext();

public IEnumerable<TblEmployee> GetAllEmployees()
{
    try
    {
        var employees = db.TblEmployee.ToList();
        return employees;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

From that, I have an `EmployeeController.cs` which I use to return my data.

Example :

```cs
DataAccessLayer objemployee = new DataAccessLayer();

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Employee/Index")]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    return new JsonResult(objemployee.GetAllEmployees());
}
```

So this is mainly my API for my data.

For my front-end code, I have a `FetchEmployee.js` which get all my employees and render them in a simple html table.

Example :

```js
export class FetchEmployee extends Component {
    displayName = FetchEmployee.name

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { empList: [], loading: true };

        fetch('api/Employee/Index', {
                method: 'get',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
            .then(response => {
                response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ empList: data, loading: false });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Something happened...', error);
            });

        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : FetchEmployee.renderEmployeeTable(this.state.empList);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Employee Data</h1>
                <p>This component demonstrates fetching <b>Employee Data</b> from the server</p>
                <p>
                    <Link to="/addemployee">Create New</Link>
                </p>
                {contents}
            </div>    
        );
    }

    //Handle the delete request from the user for an employee
    handleDelete(id) {
        fetch('api/Employee/Delete/' + id, {
            method: 'delete'
        }).then(data => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    empList: this.state.empList.filter((rec) => {
                        return (rec.employeeId != id);
                    })
                });
        });
    }

    //Handle the edit request from the user for an employee
    handleEdit(id) {
        this.props.history.push('/employee/edit/' + id);
    }

    static renderEmployeeTable(empList) {
        return (
            <table className='table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Employee Identifier</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {empList.map(emp =>
                        <tr key={emp.employeeId}>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>{emp.employeeId}</td>
                            <td>{emp.name}</td>
                            <td>{emp.gender}</td>
                            <td>{emp.department}</td>
                            <td>{emp.city}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a className='action' onClick={(id) => this.handleEdit(emp.employeeId)}>Edit</a>  |
                                <a className='action' onClick={(id) => this.handleDelete(emp.employeeId)}>Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
```

We can agree that there's nothing to fancy here. It's a simple `GET` and nothing more, but I always get this error :

`Unexpected token '<' json at position 0`

Whatever what I'm trying to do.

Those are my routes from `App.js` :

```js
    <Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/fetchemployee' component={FetchEmployee} />
    </Layout>
```

And this is my `Network Tab`

[image: Network Activity]

Can you help me figuring this one out? Do you have any ideas why I'm returning `HTML` from my controller?

[Edit]

When I added `"Accept": "application/json"` to my headers for my `fetch()`, I got a 404 telling me :

```
Cannot GET api/Employee/Index
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that you're not propagating the json result in your promise chain:

```
.then(...)
.then(response => {
  response.json(); // <-- missing a return statement or you can eliminate the {}
})
.then(...)
```

You would need something like:

```
.then(...)
.then(response =>
  response.json() // return the json promise so it can propagate down the chain
)
.then(...)
```

In general, the common reason for your given error message is receiving HTML but expecting JSON.

```
Unexpected token '<' json at position 0
```

Means that your payload looks like `<html>...</html>` but you're trying to parse it as JSON and this happens:

```js
try {
  JSON.parse('<html>...</html>')
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

Comment: I eliminated the {} (still have the 404), but do you have a solution or explanation for why I'm returning `HTML` instead of `JSON`? Am I unable to access my DB?

Comment: Check the headers of your request, and response, validate that the content type is proper json, make sure your endpoint indeed returns a json. Maybe use curl or Postman to query it directly so you can isolate the problem to the backend or frontend.

Comment: I tried launching my IIS Express from Visual Studio 2017, entering, in Postman, the `URL + /api/Employee/Index` and it returned me `HTML`. My `public/index.html` with default `HTML` code...

Comment: So that's your problem then. Your endpoint returns HTML but you're parsing it as JSON. It seems that the issue is on the backend and thus in the .NET land, not JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure of what exactly is causing the problem! My `AccessLayer` is returning an `IEnumerable<TblEmployee>` and my `Controller` is returning is as json : `return Json(objemployee.GetAllEmployees());`